# Domino Designer 9 used to modify apps destiined to 8.5.3 client

Tags: lotus-notes, domino-designer-eclipse

I have been using the Designer 9 client to modify apps destined to users that have the 8.5.3 client in a company for 2 years, and I never had any issues with users not seeing design elements modified with my Designer 9.  New job, same setup: clients are using 8.5.3 and I am using Designer 9.0.1 to modify apps built in 8.5.3.  But here, I had issues in 2 apps where some users don't see the nivagator, or a view that has a new alias is not recognized by some users.

I am unsure if this is related to me using Designer 9 to modify apps that end up in the 8.5.3 client, but it has put enough doubts in the admins minds that they asked me to revert to the 8.5.3 Designer.

Anyone had similar issues with a similar setup?  I am not adding any new design elements, just modifying things like forms, navigators, outlines.

Any idea what might be the issue?  For now, I did return to the 8.5.3 Designer and it seems that the users who had issues are now OK.  But is it really the Designer version or just some other issue (like the "refreshed flag" that was not updated properly, or any other obscure thing)?

I'd really like to find the answer so I can install Designer 9 again, and start building XPages demo apps  :D

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a consultant and work with Designer 9 since it came out. Lot of my clients still use 8.5.3 clients and I never had any issue with this constellation.

As far as I know there is not even ONE new feature in "classic" development that was not there in 8.5.3...

Of course: When writing xpage- applications for XPinC, then it matters which client. For every "classic" application if for sure doesn't...